# parse cookie string with javascript and use the data to pull in html

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Here's my situation. I have a project where my back end .Net team will be passing me a cookie such as:

```
COOKIE=ID=1&NAME=Foo&AGE=30&EMPLOYED=Y&ACTIVE=N
```

Then I need to parse this data, and set up conditionals per the data for what HTML I want to pull into my page. Basically fill in empty divs with HTML that would be mapped to what the string values declare.

Has anyone ever worked on something like this? My first thought is to split the string, create an array, and then somehow parse out the values. Then map them to individual unique HTML files.

I appreciate any help! I've worked with cookies before, but never something like this.

Comment: Why not have the back end generate the correct html since they have all the data and not do the unnecessary round trip back to the client?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is that you figure out the correct html at your back-end code instead of the front-end.

I have created a local cookie as per your test value you have provided.
The code below, sets a local cookie and fetches it, splits the key-value pairs and displays them.

P.S. Google Chrome by default disables the local cookies, so this may appear to not work. Just try in IE, this has been created just as a demonstration for you.

Here is the solution per your requirement:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var testCookie="COOKIE=ID=1&NAME=Foo&AGE=30&EMPLOYED=Y&ACTIVE=N";

    function setCookie(cname,exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = testCookie+"; "+expires;
    }

    function getCookie(name) {
         var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }

    function checkCookie() {
        var c=getCookie("COOKIE");
        var cookieElements = [];
        cookieElements = c.split("&");
        var cookieNameValuePairs = "Name   |   Value\n";
        var keyValue = [];
        for(i=0;i<cookieElements.length;i++){
            keyValue = cookieElements[i].split("=");
            cookieNameValuePairs += keyValue[0] + "   |   " + keyValue[1] + "\n";
        }

        alert(cookieNameValuePairs);
    }

</script>

</head>

<body onload="checkCookie()"></body>
</html>
```